# Why is there no preposition in between "idea" and "what" in the sentence "I have no idea what he likes."?

Tags: prepositions

> > I have no idea what he likes.

In the upper sentence, there is no preposition in between "idea" and "what".
I wonder the reason why this is.

I already checked out other questions similar to this one, but there was no reason explained for this.
All answers say that it is just the way it is.
But could you give me any proper guess for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "compound verb" here is *to have no idea*. The syntax is exactly the same with many other verbs - for example, *I **know** what he likes, I **cook** what he likes, I **don't care** what he likes*.

Note that in some contexts with some verbs, the preposition ***about*** can be introduced. Sometimes this simply isn't possible (*I cook **about** what he likes* doesn't make much sense). But in other contexts, including ***about*** may subtly affect the meaning. Thus...

> 1: *I know what he wants*
>    2: *I know **about** what he wants*

...where (1) may simply mean *I **can identify** what he wants*. Perhaps we're in an Indian restaurant, and I'm about to tell the waiter that I know my friend wants a [Bombay Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombay_duck) as an appetiser (I may not know anything else ***about*** exactly what a Bombay Duck is, but I know that's what he wants).

Note that (2) above is idiomatically unlikely in most contexts, but one that you might encounter occurs in contexts like...

> *"Shall we go on a boat trip, or sunbathe on the beach? John wants to sunbathe"*
>    3: *"Yeah, yeah! We know [all] about what John wants! He just wants to ogle girls in bikinis!"*

Even in (3), most people probably wouldn't include *[all] **about***. But at least it doesn't sound "odd".

Comment: This topic (optional preposition use) seems to come up a lot. Is there a grammar rule that covers it?

Comment: A "grammar rule"??? I think you're being a bit optimistic there! :) English uses prepositions ***a lot*** to make subtle (or "unsubtle") distinctions, but trying to explain all the different ways we do this would fill several books (and still only scratch the surface). There might be a few principles that apply in enough contexts to be be worth learners knowing about, but there are a lot more that don't really fit into any recognizable pattern.

Comment: ...bear in mind that most native speakers have almost no conscious knowledge of such matters (we're not usually taught much about it in school; we just learn by copying others).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of such a rule either, it is just what we learned to say. But a rule would make this easier to explain, rather than "sometimes people drop the preposition".

Comment: Well, in the specific example presented by OP here it doesn't make much sense to talk about *dropping the preposition*, since normally there's no reason why we'd even *have* a preposition that might be dropped. It would be out-and-out ungrammatical to drop ***of*** when saying you're *not aware of something*. As explained, you *can* discard it in *don't know [of, about] something* - but again, it's not really just a "meaningless" optional choice. As usual, the precise phrasing adopted usually carries at least *some* nuance of difference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is so helpful. Thank you for your help and the time and energy for this. I wish you have a good luck in the future.