# "I have no idea <of> what you're talking about." — By what rule can we take "of" away here?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, parsing, functions, content-clauses

my own examples:
**(1)** *No idea **of** what we will do occured to me*. — I think it's correct.
**(2)** *No idea what we will do occured to me*. — I think it's incorrect.
That is, "*of*" is obligatory.

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/idea):
**(3)** *I have no idea what you're talking about*. — I would have thought it was not correct without a preposition but the dictionary says it is.
As far as I understand, the fact that there isn't a preposition between a noun and an interrogative content clause violates the English grammar.
What makes (3) an exclusion to the rules?
What does the interrogative content clause "*what you're talking about*" in (3) function as?

my variant:
**(4)** *I have no idea **of** what you're talking about*. — I think it's correct and fits the normal grammar rules.
The interrogative content clause "*what you're talking about*" functions as the complement of the preposition "*of*".
The prepositional phrase "*of what you're talking about*" functions as the modifier to the noun "*idea*".

Comment: Have you researched the topic of [ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis) (the omission of common words, _not_ the three dots like this...)?

Comment: (1) isn't correct. The sentence refers to a moment in the past, so it should be "No idea of what we _would_ do occurred to me"  or, better still, "...of what to do".

Comment: @KateBunting "_No idea of what we **will** do occured to me._" — I wrote "_will_" to show the moment in future when we will do something hasn't come yet. Why is such an explanation of using "_will_" incorrect here? Thanks.

Comment: There are some constructions where the preposition is optional, as it is in your example: "I have no idea (of) what you're talking about". Thus, the content clause may be complement of the preposition "of" or directly of the noun "idea".

Comment: I understood the sentence to be part of a narrative about the past. If you are talking about the present moment, it would have to be "occurs to me" - but that's a very convoluted way of saying "I have no idea what to do."

Comment: @KateBunting I'll explain in more detail what I meant. In your version: "_No idea of what we **would** do occured to me_." — "no idea occuring to me" was in the past, "us doing something" was in the past too. In my version: "_No idea of what we **will** do occured to me_." — "no idea occuring to me" was in the past, but "us doing something" has not happened yet and will happen only in future (the future as to the moment when the sentence was said). That's why I used "_will_". So why is such an explanation of using "will" incorrect here?

Comment: Because "what we will do" refers to the future from **now**. If you are speaking of someone in the past thinking of the future from the viewpoint of that time, you have to use "what we **would** do".

Comment: @KateBunting The explanation (which I gave you) of using "_will_" in (1) is the same as [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7560/82229): "It is ... not obligatory to use 'will' ... if it refers to an event which is still in the future at the time the sentence is uttered." — But you don't agree with it, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed you _can_ (but don't have to) use "will" if the occasion for "doing something" hasn't arisen yet. But this discussion is straying from the main point of your question.

Comment: @KateBunting So in the end, you began to consider "_will_" in (1) correct, right?

Comment: **Only** if the speaker was thinking in the past about an action by 'us' which hasn't happened yet - which didn't occur to me as the default interpretation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no preposition in between "idea" and "what" in the sentence "I have no idea what he likes."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83723/why-is-there-no-preposition-in-between-idea-and-what-in-the-sentence-i-have)

Comment: @StuartF No, but thank you for the link. On that link: i) A user suggests to consider the whole phrase "_to have no idea_" as one verb. ii) There isn't parsing I asked for in the original post.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You didn’t explain how your question and your link relate to the original post. So unfortunately I don't know how to consider your comment other than one that is unclear or even can mislead.

Comment: the verb suggest **does not take to**.